# Reading the lines of small c# code and what do they mean

Tags: c#, parent-child

my question is very simple for those who know the job very well.
How is this code read line by line, especially the 3 commented ones?

```
private formMain parent = null; //explanation 1
public formChild(formMain parent) //explanation 2
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.parent = parent; //explanation 3
}
```

My thougths:
- explanation 1: creating reference parent of formMain that has null value. That 'null' I really don't know what does it mean, I want explanation for that. Maybe a null value because it must be initializated before use?
- explanation 2: passing object of parent form in the constructor of child form?
- explanation 3: this.parent refers to the private member (which is in the first line) and = parent refers to the member in the arguments list of the constructor?

And in the parent form there is small code when initializating the child form passing (this) in the constructor for (formMain parent) which I think it's passing the current form.

This code I found on internet, it's working perfectly and it is used for accessing properties of parent form from child form.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

P.S. Please comment using this kind of template:
- explanation 1:
- explanation 2:
- explanation 3:

Comment: @Skurmedel, yes it is :(

Comment: How can a comment questioning whether this is homework be considered 'great', 3 times? To me this kind of comment only becomes relevant when there has been no personal enquiry on behalf of the OP other than determining that they want to know something. The OP clearly puts some effort and makes this question no different to any other out-of-schooling request. The schooling side of it is relevant when we're asked to essentially do work _for them_, not just in _aiding_ them. Pah! Are you going to start asking others _'Is this for your boss?_, or something else so obviously similar?

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: I do not understand. The reasons I ask are two: 1) simply answering anything homework related here in any way considered "wrong" exposes you to downvotes from the Templars of Pedagogics. 2) the question more or less requires someone to do all the work for the OP, *and* a format for answering was asked for, leaving me to wonder if it was just to be copy-pasted into some school work. I do thank your the fine conclusions about my character you derived from three words and a question mark.

Comment: @Skurmedel
It won't be just copy-pasted, I will need this to explain and to use it in my future apps (when I learn more, obviously). It's always good to know what you are doing, not just coding without understanding.

Comment: @Skurmedel: By the first point can we conclude that interest is in _what the community thinks_ as opposed to actually _helping the OP_? Disconcerting, but no real surprise. Secondly, effort is put into what the OP _does_ know, it's only natural to ask what you _don't_ and in the name of learning, why would you provide a different answer to any user, surely they all deserve the same amount of info you're enabled to give in a format they can learn from equally? Thirdly, the format requirement I can agree on as looking 'suspicious' to some, but I think its a little judgemental - even if correct.

Comment: @Skurmedel: My usage of 'you' was to mean the collective, not you personally.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: No I'm interested in avoiding pointless discussions with people about the correct way to teach someone on the internet, which usually removes any enjoyment I may experience writing my answer. My presence here is for my benefit as well, it's not an altruistic exercise. The general consensus here regarding homework seems to be to not do everything for the student; I am not necessarily of the same opinion, but by now you know why I care about this. In short I want to know so I can avoid answering.

Comment: @Skurmedel: The general consensus here is that we don't do everything for the OP - not necessarily making special cases of people; someone either asks a good question or they don't. I'm not saying homework posts aren't different in certain senses, but on the whole, the same rules should apply throughout SO, which, if we subscribe to, could cut a lot of this pointlessness out. However, if we wish to proceed this discussion, it should probably be elsewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- explanation 1: You are creating a variable called `parent` to hold something. The "something" that it will hold is a `formMain`. By setting it to `null` you are saying you don't have the specific `formMain` yet, but you know you should have one eventually.
- explanation 2: You are creating a method which creates an instance of a `formChild`. This object (`formChild`) has a dependency on a `formMain`. Even though the dependency has the same name as the one from explanation 1 they are not the same (not yet).
- explanation 3: The externally passed in `formMain` called `parent` (from explanation 2) is getting assigned to the internally stored `parent` from explanation 1. Now the rest of the methods in the object which has just been created can reference the external dependency.

So the way you would use this code is something like this

```
//from a formMain type object. 
formChild childForm = new formChild(this);

//from the formChild object
this.parent.Title = "Title of parent being changed from child"
```

Comment: One note; the assignment of `parent` to `null` when it's declared is redundant. When declaring a variable without assigning a value, it has the "default", which for all reference types like forms is null.

Answer (score 0):

I used to comment like this when i was very new, but after a while you insane this with level of commenting that, and instead explain what the purpos of a function/part is.

IE You dont need to explain that you setting Partent = null, because the code already says that, you explain why your setting it to null.

Comment: I was asking why it was setting to null, I know it's set :)
maybe I mispointed or you misunderstand, nevermind, I get the answer :D thanks to all anyway

Answer (score 0):

Explanation #2 is correct (and #3 is pretty close too).

The child form is keeping the reference to it's parent by assigning it to a private member variable. The main reason you would want to keep the reference is for communicating back to the parent, or accessing public properties or functions back in the parent form.

Answer (score 0):

1: It is never a bad idea to initialize variables or objects. Unless you know that initial values you want variables to have `null` is usually a better choice (the alternative in most cases is to have some random value you know nothing of).
2: This line declares a function/method that takes one parameter of type formMain. In this case it is called `parent`.
3: This line is setting the private member `parent` equal to the parameter `parent` passed to the function. They keyword `this` represents elements contained within the class.

A rewrite more easier to understand might look like this:

```
private formMain parent = null; //explanation 1
public formChild(formMain element) //explanation 2
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.parent = element; //explanation 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for a child form is setting the reference to its parent.

Regarding the use of "this".   If the constructor contained the assignment there would be a problem.

```
parent = parent; //this is circular
```

In order to reference the private filed by the same name (outside of the constructor), 'this' is pre-pended:

```
this.parent = parent; //assign the value of the param to the private field
```

Other comments.  The style seems to be borrowed from Java and would not be typical for C#.

```
class FormChild
{

    private FormParent _parent; //reference types are automatically null

    public FormChild( FormParent parent)//pass in the reference to the parent
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       _parent = parent; //assign the reference param to the private field.
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, it we are on hurry and we are learning 2 weeks in 1 week, so that's why I'm losing some points, but thanks to all of you for helping me

Comment: That null was making me problems, so it musn't be typed as it's by default, if I understand well.
Well explanation, thanks for your efforts.